# Powershell sequence output logic

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, syntax

I have a powershell script which creates a text file as a output in sequence number starting from 0 to 10(for example). out of which I have to pick 3 and 5 and create a output in sequence order starts from 0. Im trying the below script but it doesnt works

```
$afcount=5
for($v=0;$v -lt $afcount; $v++)
{
Get-Content "C:\del2\out($v).txt" | Foreach-Object { 
    if ($_ -match "AI_SERVICE_CONNECTOR") 
    {
        $_    
    }
} | Add-Content "C:\del2\outAI_Service_Connector($v).txt"
$afcount1=(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\del2\outAI_Service_Connector($v).txt"  -Recurse | Measure-Object).Count
$afcount1
Get-Content "C:\del2\outAI_Service_Connector($v).txt" | Foreach-Object {
    for($i=$null; $i -lt $afcount1; $i++)
    {
        Get-Content "C:\del2\outAI_Service_Connector($v).txt"  | Set-Content "C:\del2\AI_Service_Connector($i).txt"
    }   
}
}
```

Input file as below
outAI_Service_Connector(4).txt
outAI_Service_Connector(6).txt

Expected output:
outAI_Service_Connector(4).txt to be created as AI_Service_Connector(1).txt
outAI_Service_Connector(6).txt to be created as AI_Service_Connector(2).txt

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the problem? What have you tried to solve it? What are your thoughts on how should the problem be approached?

Comment: This script creating just one file and puts both the content in one file, I need the file 2 to be mapped to 0 and file 5 to be mapped to 1, I wanted to know where i'm missing.

Comment: `for($i=$null ...` --> `for($i=0 ...`, but your question is very unclear. Can you give some examples to clarify please?

Comment: Are you trying to append the content from one log to the other or are you just taking the content from one and overwriting the other?  If the latter, you could just rename the file rather than getting and setting the content

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. I have set of files named 0 to 10, out of which I have to pick 2 ,5 ,8 and rename those files in Iterative manner(0,1,2,3 and so on)

Comment: ..but then you will get naming collisions because file(0) already exists..